# How to make X-Signature from private key? android

Tags: android, kotlin, rsa, signature, private-key

What I need is from my private-key which looks like this

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQg0m4yLz+sdzZtBG9Q
HQ9++wcfq1O4hOWgSBMb/A6eijyhRANCAAQeB0fBl2D7HZOKVBjpPiU2jabzNxQU
ZYrJ+MSA3LpzZxmRk2JaFHNujjkJghQT19HHjg3Fnkb8Y9oIhB9neXBI
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

(I removed spaces, header and footer)

Get X-Signature which is ECDSA (SHA256) signature as UTF-8 from X-Timestamp in DER format.
Where X-Timestamp is Unix timestamp of current time without ms (like this 1623076761)

X-Signature should look like this:

```
304402201429f934eedbf9b66b89dc88dbb45bec90a8819d8435acd6db90f6f00e3c80cc022032bc765dfb0d3203a92c3080e5fc71dc1b17ecf7c8089261be482fe30aa8a6bd
```

Kill me xD

What I did is:

```
val privateKeyString = "myKey"
val sigBytes: ByteArray = Base64Utils.decode(privateKeyString)

val privateKeySpec = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(sigBytes)
val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")

val privateKey : PrivateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec)
```

I got privateKey as PrivateKey object

```
val unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L
```

Got X-Timestamp

```
val signature: ByteArray? = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA").run {
    initSign(privateKey)
    update("$unixTime".toByteArray())
    sign()
}

val signatureResult : String = Base64Utils.encode(signature)
```

And then I did this. I don't really understand what should be `update(HERE.toByteArray())` and how to connect X-Timestamp with signature and how to make it in DER forma as well.

I don't know xD. Is it really to solve this?

Comment: @user9014097 I know that you are genius, pls help)

Comment: You cannot @ persons that are not part of an active conversation. Which particular standard are you working on? Signatures generated should already be in DER form (the example that you have shown is). However, without a standard referenced I cannot tell what the input for the signature should be.